# Forming Tuple for Graph Processing in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the data as following

```
3,3,2
4,1,3
1,1,2
1,3,0
0,6,3
2,2,3
0,2,1
0,5,2
```

I want to be able to build a tuple of the form

```
(2,Long.MAX_VALUE,((3,2)(1,1)(0,5))
(3,Long.MAX_VALUE,((4,1)(0,6)(2,2))
(0,Long.MAX_VALUE,((1,3))
(1,Long.MAX_VALUE,((0,2))
```

I imported the data from a text file and used a mapper to form

```
(3,(2,3))
(4,(3,1))
```

and so on

I tried using a map to convert all these to the form

```
(0,Long.MAX_VALUE,(1,3)
```

and then i am using `groupBy(x => (x._1,x._2))` but am unable to form these tuples. What am i doing wrong

i am getting tuples of the form

(0,Long.MAX_VALUE,((0,Long.MAX_VALUE,1,3))

Comment: can you elaborate how you arrive at your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like below to get your expected output

```
   val rdd = sc.textFile("path to your text file")
   val rdd2 = rdd.map(line => line.split(","))
      .groupBy(array => array(2))
      .mapValues(arrays => arrays.map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1))))
      .map(a => (a._1, Long.MaxValue, a._2))
```

And `rdd2.foreach(println)` should print

```
(0,9223372036854775807,List((1,3)))
(2,9223372036854775807,List((3,3), (1,1), (0,5)))
(3,9223372036854775807,List((4,1), (0,6), (2,2)))
(1,9223372036854775807,List((0,2)))
```

I hope the answer is helpful and you should have general idea on how to proceed. :)